# Does a magnitude of a vector always have to be non-negative?

Tags: vectors, geometry

If components of a vector can be positive OR negative OR zero, why must the magnitude of a vector always be non-negative?

Comment: you can describe a vector as  having  a magnitude (positive) and a direction  (angle relative to some axis), or as having components along the axes, which can be either positive or negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vector is a quantity described by a magnitude and a direction.  The magnitude is always +ve or zero.  A -ve sign in front of a vector indicates the same magnitude but in the opposite direction.  The - sign is part of the direction rather than the magnitude.

Like all vectors, a "resultant vector" is neither +ve or -ve. It has a magnitude (which is >= 0) and a direction.

"Components" are scalars.  They are the projections of a vector onto the x and y axes (or other axes).  They are not magnitudes, because they can be +ve or -ve (as you note) depending on the angle between the vector and the axes. The + or - sign indicates the direction of the projection along the axis.

"Component vectors" are vectors resolved in the x and y directions which add up to the given vector.  Since they are vectors they have magnitude and direction - although the only possible directions are the +x/-x and +y/-y directions.  They are not +ve or -ve, because these terms do not apply to vectors.

I apologise that this answer may not be mathematically rigorous.  The whole issue is confusing, as your question shows.  I am trying to distinguish between the different terms being used.

Comment: But why do you consider components to be "scalar projections" while you consider resultant magnitude to be a "vector with direction"? Both give distance and an angle on a graph. So shouldn't they both be considered vectors with direction?

Comment: " -ve magnitude indicates the opposite direction" is not really right. The -ve sign is a part of the direction unit vector associated with the vector and not a part of the magnitude. A minus sign before a unit vector indicates that the direction is opposite to the direction of the unit vector. The magnitude remains unchanged when you change the sign.

Comment: @OrdinaryOwl : The resultant is a vector.  I did not write that the "resultant magnitude is a vector."  When you are discussing components you need to be clear about whether you are talking about scalars or vectors.

Comment: @YashasSamaga : Thank you for pointing out my error.  I have edited my answer.  The topic is a tricky one for a physicist to deal with.  Perhaps rigorous mathematical definitions are required.